# where to import the jquery.js file

Tags: jquery

I was wondering where I should write the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` in a php project.
I wrote it in the main file menu.phpm in the head and I then include this file in other files but if I do that the jquery functions I use don't work in the other files while if I add again `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` in the other file, it work.
Do I have to write that in every file in which I use jquery functions?

thank you

Comment: find the answer below. But this is very very basic question. you can get the answer immediately, when you google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you don't need to have jquery.js in each file. It should be called in only one file in between `<head> </head>` tag , let's say **menu.php** and that menu.php should be included in each and every page. remember to include menu.php before you use jQuery functions.

Comment: Thanks, I included menu.php after writing the javascript functions in other-file.php, that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Wherever you use jquery functions, you have to include this script before the function calling. If you use 10 files, you have to include in all. I would suggest you if you have any common header file, include Jquery.js in that file.

Comment: even if I write '<?php include("menu.php"); ?>' in the other file and have already added the jquery file in menu.php? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: @morg if menu.php has jquery.js, then you dont need to include again in the other file.

Comment: So that's my question... I've been SEARCHING on google but didn't find the answer, so please don't say I didn't.The answer was only that I included menu.php after writing the javascript functions in other-file.php, my mistake.

Comment: @morg cool. See your question. It is not relevant to your problem now. Even it doesnt have any code example. Then how can we assume what do you want exactly?

Comment: It can happen to everyone to made some basic mistakes. I'm sorry to be new to web developing, I don't see why you needed to suppose I didn't search before asking. I don't think you were here. Moreover code example is irrelevant here, you don't have to know what i have written after the javascript tags to answer the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using root relative path for src rather than document relative path

Answer (score 0):

You should include this file to every page where you are going to use functions from this file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to add jquery file in all pages where you use jquery functions.

If you have `index.php` which will include other php files dynamically, add `jquery.js` just in the head section of this file and all is ok

**index.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
         // write your jquery functions after you've included the jquery.js file
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php include("path/to/other/files/other_file.php"); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

**other_file.php**

```
<div>This is some content included dinamically</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file named as "imports.php" and import this file in it. After that make sure u import imports.php in every file's header before calling jquery's method.